# Automatization of document generation

Tags: pdf, automation

I want to create one big document which will be based on many PDFs. In output I want to have at least 300 pages.

Requirements:

1. Bookmark feature is very important.
2. Software/solution needs to run under Win 7 without admin rights.
3. Free/open source software solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a possibility would be LaTeX:

- free open source
- has index etc.
- no size limitations

Especially of interest will be the command `\includepdf`, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360907/any-way-to-add-pdf-report-as-an-appendix-in-latex/360909

A good further starting point would be to google: latex include pdf